# What is "cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition" in java testing?

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, automation-testing

I have written a code to test adding items into an inventory but i keep getting Arity mismatch error.

My code is as follows:

```
@When("^(Coffee|Milk|Sugar|Chocolate) is (.*)$")
    @Then("^Inventory is successfully added\\.$")
    public void inventory_is_successfully_added(String Coffee, String milk, String sugar, String chocolate) throws InventoryException {
        
        coffeeMaker.addInventory(Coffee,milk,sugar,chocolate);
        System.out.println("Inventory is successfully added.");
    }
```

and the corresponding Scenario written in feature file is this:

```
Scenario: Add Inventory
        When Coffee is 4
        When Milk is 7 
        When Sugar is 0
        When Chocolate is 9
        Then Inventory is successfully added.
```

This is the error I get:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'edu.ncsu.csc326.coffeemaker.TestSteps.inventory_is_successfully_added(String,String,String,String) in file:/D:/newEclipse/Assign/build/classes/java/test/' with pattern [^(Coffee|Milk|Sugar|Chocolate) is (.*)$] is declared with 4 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 2 arguments [Coffee, 4].
```

can someone please tell me what it means?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

This Exception means that the number of capture groups in your step does not match the number of parameters defined in your step definition.

In your example, the step `@When("^(Coffee|Milk|Sugar|Chocolate) is (.*)$")` has 2 capture groups: `(Coffee|Milk|Sugar|Chocolate)` and `(.*)` and the step `@Then("^Inventory is successfully added\\.$")` has no capture groups.
The step definition `public void inventory_is_successfully_added(String Coffee, String milk, String sugar, String chocolate)` defines 4 parameters: `String Coffee`, `String milk`, `String sugar`, `String chocolate`.

Cucumber is throwing this exception, because it doesn't know which values to pass to the parameters.

To fix this:

1. Implement the step where you add the amount of `(Coffee|Milk|Sugar|Chocolate)` if you haven't already (your example does not provide the implementation).
2. Implement the step definition for inventory_is_successfully_added() so that the method does not take any parameters, and inside the method get the values provided for `coffee`, `milk`, etc from your test context.